# Android puzzle about AnimationSet.addAnimation()

Tags: android

I am Chinese and poor at English, I hope that the following description would not confuse you...
First one:

```
animationSet.addAnimation(animation3D);
animationSet.addAnimation(animationTranslate);
```

Second one：

```
 animationSet.addAnimation(animationTranslate);
 animationSet.addAnimation(animation3D);
```

I found they are different, the first one is smooth but second not.

The code of animation3D is:

```
public class ThreeDRotateAnimation extends Animation {
int centerX, centerY;
Camera camera = new Camera();

@Override
public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth,
                       int parentHeight) {
    super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    centerX = width / 2;
    centerY = height / 2;
    setDuration(500);
    setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();
    camera.save();
    camera.rotateY(360 * interpolatedTime);
    camera.getMatrix(matrix);
    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
    matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
    camera.restore();
}
```

}

And the code of animationTranslate is very simple:

```
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="-50%p"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:toYDelta="0%"/>
```

But I really don't know why they are different?
Does the order of addAnimation can lead to different result?
I really need your help!!!

Comment: *Does the order of addAnimation can lead to different result?* obviously. Isn't that the cause of this question?

Comment: But I don't know why...I used to add both  RotateAnimation and TranslateAnimation into AnimationSet, and it works well. But why add animation3D and TranslateAnimation doesn't work? Is that because the animation3D?